# How to create loading screen in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

The game I am working on needs a camera but it takes some time to load, making the game window unresponsive.

To load the camera, I am using OpenCV:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

Is there any way to create a loading screen while doing this?

Comment: Do you want it to be a progress bar representing every step of the camera being set up or just a simple splash screen?

Comment: I searched about splash screen but I don't really understand what it is. Is it a screen that do not to be updated?

Answer (score 1):

You can either draw the loading screen before you load the camera(Create an unresponsive screen) or use multithreading to open the loading screen in another thread.